# Como chamar uma função original em um método sobrecarregado em php

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Preciso executar o versão do pai de um método sobrecarregado em php, é possível?

Ex.:

```
public function delete()
{
    // executa código extra e depois executa o método original
    super->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando existem mais níveis de herança pode ser necessário usar o nome da classe ao invés de `parent`, o trecho de código abaixo exemplifica os usos para cada caso.

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public function exemplo() {}
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function exemplo() {
        parent::exemplo(); // chama da classe pai: Foo::exemplo()
    }
}

class Foobar extends Bar {
    public function exemplo() {
        parent::exemplo(); // chama da classe pai: Bar::exemplo()
        Foo::exemplo(); // chama da classe avô
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sim, usa-se `parent::`

```
public function delete()
{
    // executa código extra e depois executa o método original
    parent::delete();
}
```